# Scale-Invariant CRPS Alternative

Tags: forecasting, scoring-rules, probabilistic-forecasts

I am currently working on a probabilistic forecasting problem (outputting the full predictive distribution, possibly in the form of samples) and I need to decide on a measure to evaluate the forecasts.

Considering I do not have an explicit density function, so likelihood-based metrics are out of the question, I have mainly seen CRPS.

However, in my case, I need to have a metric which is comparable between different processes I have to predict for, similarly to how I would use WAPE (WMAPE, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WMAPE) for point prediction. This is not true for CRPS which is not scale-invariant. While a scale-invariant alternative exist (https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.05642), it seems to have some disadvantages. The main one I see is that, while CRPS reduces to MAE for point prediction, SCRPS does not reduce to anything and, on the contrary, it will diverge for a point prediction which is not the true distribution. In fact, while it is still a proper scoring rule, a confident prediction close, but not exactly equal to the actuals, would make the denominator explode.
I have thought of just dividing CRPS by the actuals, which would reduce to APE in case of point predictions, but cannot find this solution anywhere, though its robustness (lack of actually) property should not be too different and it should make the metric scale invariant (this is roughly my intuition, but it could be that it is actually not scale-invariant).

Why is this metric never used? Does it carry some problematic disadvantages? I understand that, if the actuals are zero, it could fail, as (M)APE does, but if we consider the equivalent of WAPE for CRPS, this disadvantages would, to a certain extent, go away.

Finally, is there some other metric that can have a more intuitive meaning in your opinion?

Sorry for the long post and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by actuals is not recommended for several reasons. First, as you've already mentioned, there might be actuals equal to zero, or otherwise very small. Second, it is not interpretable.

The WMAPE solution is not great either for point forecasting, as it is not really interpretable, and (when optimized) doesn't lead to any sensible point forecast.

I suggest you use a skill score instead. That is the CRPS from your method relative to the CRPS from some benchmark method. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/distaccuracy.html#scale-free-comparisons-using-skill-scores for a discussion and further details.